# How to place a button over JFrame title bar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, setbounds

I want to place a button on the JFrame title bar as in the below image.

[image: Expected window]

When I set the bounds for the button using button.setBounds(), the button hides under the title bar as below.

[image: Window Appear]

I have given below the code that I had tried.

```
public class SetBoundsTest {
       public static void main(String arg[]) {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
          frame.setSize(500, 250);
          // Setting layout as null
          frame.setLayout(null);
          
          // Creating Button
          JButton button = new JButton("Test");
          // Setting position and size of a button
          button.setBounds(150,-20,120,40);

          button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 3));
          button.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
          frame.add(button);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
       }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I want to place a button on the JFrame title bar as in the below image."* . . Why?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, In our application we need to have controls on the title bar as in MS word, excel, etc.

Comment: The title bar is part of the OS component and java doesn't have access to it. If you want a custom title bar then you need to use an undecorated frame and add your own title bar as has already been suggested. You could try using the Metal LAF. It does create its own title bar. So you could get the root pane of the frame and then search the child components until you find the custom title bar. Then based on the layout manager used in the title bar you might be able to insert your own components.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your frame to undecorated like this

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Note: Add this statement before `frame.setVisiblle(true);`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 

Can we place the button on top of the existing title bar? If we set undecorate, we have to create our own title bar.

Comment: There will be no title bar when the frame is undecorated. You would need to create your own in whichever fashion you like.

Answer (score 0):

Two years late to the party, but I was able to do this without `frame.setUndecorated(true)` directly using FlatLaf with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWlfe_O12lY

Just keep in mind that FlatLaf *may* not remain consistent across all systems if used in this manner.

FlatLaf github repo: https://github.com/JFormDesigner/FlatLaf

**Launcher**

`.show()` is just a function where I am initializing other panels/objects in my demo project.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                FlatLaf.registerCustomDefaultsSource("com.testui.themes");
                FlatDarculaLaf.setup();
                new EpicWindow().show();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ...
            }
        });
    }
```

**FlatLaf.properties Config**

`com/testui/themes/FlatLaf.properties`

```
TitlePane.unifiedBackground=false
```

**The Button!**

Then wherever you load your panels into jframe, you need to create a JMenueBar

```
...
// Just an example..
JButton btn = new JButton("huh?");
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

menuBar.putClientProperty(FlatClientProperties.STYLE, ""
                + "borderColor:$TitlePane.background;"
                + "border:0,0,0,0");

menuBar.add(btn);
jFrameWindow.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
...
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReAos.png)